# Expo no longer working? bash: expo: command not found

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

so I am working on some React Native projects and up until now, Expo has been working great along with Android Studio. However, I think I updated my graphics card drivers a couple of days ago. Now when I try to run "expo start" I receive a "bash: expo: command not found" error.

Any ideas? I keep seeing all this stuff about adding NPM global to my paths but all of those issues/solutions seem to be for Mac. I have no idea how to go about correcting this on a Windows 10 machine. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

expo is not installed on the machine anymore for some reason
since it is an expo project it is straightforward first go to [Nodejs webpage](https://nodejs.org/en/)
download **LTS version** NOT THE CURRENT VERSION once node is succesfully installed on the machine it will you can check by opening the command prompt and typing `node --version`
you should see something like "14.1232."
then run this command `npm install -g expo-cli` it should install expo again globally
navigate to your project folder and do "expo start" it should work

Comment: So, I ended up restarting my computer and everything works fine for some reason now. Weird. Thanks for the help though, I'll try that next time.